# How can I 'tell' each CPU core what to do in MATLAB?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, optimization, parallel-processing

Instead of `parfor` loop I want to create 4 threads and write out the code for each individually. What's the syntax for that?

Comment: Do you really want to control which thread runs on which core? Using parallel computing in matlab you typically distribute the jobs among the worker threads, not specifying which or how many cores do the job.

Comment: @Daniel46 Well, I have 4 different things to be done independent of each other, all 4 of them take same amount of time, can't I distribute them on 4 cores? Or suppose I have 3 different things to be done in parallel, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I recommend to use Edric's answer or [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/program-independent-jobs-on-a-local-cluster.html) solution**

(I leave the answer here for the comments.)

Forget about cores, you want to distribute your tasks among your worker processes.

Simple "hack" solution:

```
n=4
result=cell(4,1)
parfor idx=1:n
   switch idx
      case 1
         r=f()
      case 2
         r=g(1)
      case 3
         r=g(2)
      case 4
         r=h()
   end
   result{idx}=r
end
```

For a more advanced solution, I recommend to create individual jobs and submit them. This is explained in detail [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/program-independent-jobs-on-a-local-cluster.html). In your case you create a job with four tasks, then you submit it. The biggest advantage of this solution is, that you avoid unnecessary broadcasting of variables.

In both solutions you don't control which worker processes which task, but you typically don't want to do this.

Comment: Well, it works however it turns out my problem isn't big enough to benefit from this, thank you anyways! I'm sure I'll use this hack some other day. And by the way `result{idx}=r` should be outside the `switch` right? After the `end`

Comment: Ah, fixed the result. When using the parallel computing toolbox keep in mind that it uses inter process communication via (localhost)  network connections. Depending on the problem that adds a significant overhead.

Comment: This is an undesirable solution because you're assuming that each worker will be given a single iteration of the `parfor` loop to operate on - this is not guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: @Edric: That is right, both solutions use automatic distribution of the jobs among the workers. Same is true for your solution using `parfeval`.

Comment: That's not quite right. `parfor` batches iterations up for efficiency reasons, whereas `parfeval` does not.

Comment: @Edric: Thanks, did not knew that difference.

Comment: @Daniel Do you know why it is the case that the MATLAB PCT sends messages to localhost on shared memory machines? It is typical for MPI implementations to be able to recognize shared-memory cases and not send messages, and the PCT is MPI-based, so I am not sure why the performance in these cases is necessarily so bad. But it makes the toolbox as a whole a lot less useful, that's for sure...

Comment: @MichaelJ: Not sure if shared memory really would be faster when communication between two java processes. I know only a solution which requires three layers of shared memory communication. Anyone who is really concerned about the performance of a local pool should generate C code and enable multithreading via OpenMP instead.

Comment: @Daniel I am no expert but based on some reading, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/13503059/4674830, seem to indicate that OpenMPI will make appropriate optimizations for communication between nodes with shared physical memory.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here. The first is to use [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) where you can request several independent function evaluations, like so:

```
% The following line executes
% out = a(a1, a2, a3) on a worker. (The number 1 is the
% the number of outputs requested from the function evaluation)
% The results can be obtained using
% out = fetchOutputs(f_a);
f_a = parfeval(@a, 1, a1, a2, a3);

% and so on...
f_b = parfeval(@b, 1, b1, b2);
f_c = parfeval(@c, 1, c1);
f_d = parfeval(@d, 1, d1, d2);
```

You can retrieve the results using `fetchOutputs(f_a)` etc.

Another option is to use `spmd` like so:

```
spmd
    switch labindex
      case 1
        a();
      case 2
        b();
      ...
    end
end
```

Generally, for independent tasks, I would suggest `parfeval` since this approach is not dependent on the number of workers in your parallel pool, whereas the `spmd` approach is.

Comment: It's unclear to me how do I pass variables to those handle functions in `parfeval`

Comment: I added more explanation to the `parfeval` example - it's also all there in the doc page that I linked to.